# ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist (NSCalendarsUsageDescription)

Tags: xcode, mobile, error-handling, mobile-application, apple-developer-account

hello im software developer in small local company. And our programmer developed the mobile application that's for user base. And once he is not good to read english so I'm trying to publish his app. And as I'm very new to this industry and have some kind of lack experience of read code. when I built the mobile code with xcode and I got email like below.

Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSContactsUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).

ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose StAnd I googled a lot and still not find a answer. So I want to deep down the source code and still can't find a solution.

So do you have any solution or any same problem you dealt with it thanks. Any solutions or same dealings?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a new entry in your info.plist, with `NSContactsUsageDescription` as key and a short description of why you use them as the value (even if you don’t really use them...).

something like this:

```
<key> NSContactsUsageDescription </key>     

<string>Our app needs to use your contacts because..</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xcode, in the project directory go to the "info.plist" file and add an entry as mentioned in the image, or open the file with code and add these two lines. You have to mention the usage policy doesn't matter whether your app is using that permission or not.

```
<key> NSCameraUsageDescription </key>         
<string>AppName does/does not requires camera usage </string>       
<key> NSContactsUsageDescription </key>         
<string>AppName does/does not requires Contacts usage </string>       
<key> NSCalenderUsageDescription </key>         
<string>AppName does/does not requires Calender usage </string>
```

....
or any permission you are facing issue with

[image: click on the plus icon and add an entry here]